# Invalid token error when trying to install the jwt plugin in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, jwt

I'm trying to use Node JWT Authentication API to build a local API using the following git: https://github.com/cornflourblue/node-role-based-authorization-api

the server listens in 4000 port, but it returns me the error 'Invalid token'. why is this happening?

I have the version 1.17.5

```
const config = require('config.json');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

// users hardcoded for simplicity, store in a db for production applications
const users = [{ id: 1, username: 'test', password: 'test', firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'User' }];

module.exports = {
    authenticate,
    getAll
};

async function authenticate({ username, password }) {
    const user = users.find(u => u.username === username && u.password === password);
    if (user) {
        const token = jwt.sign({ sub: user.id }, config.secret);
        const { password, ...userWithoutPassword } = user;
        return {
            ...userWithoutPassword,
            token
        };
    }
}

async function getAll() {
    return users.map(u => {
        const { password, ...userWithoutPassword } = u;
        return userWithoutPassword;
    });
}
```

Comment: Post your code, if possible the part where you think it might be returning this message.

Comment: @JustCase I posted the code above :) i didn't change anything ... it's the code from github :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Postman to send a POST(this is important. It should be POST) request to `localhost:4000/users/authenticate`. In the Body Tab change "form-data" to "raw" and type:

```
 {
    "username":"admin",
    "password":"admin"
}
```

You will get token. Copy it. 
[Result of the POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjTjS.png)

Open a new tab to make a new GET request to `localhost:4000/users/`. On the Headers tab of Postman enter "Authorization" in the key field and 'bearer [token you copied]' to Value field. Make the request. It should return json with users.
[Result of the GET request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I79mD.png)

Comment: hello @Koby , and thanks for your help: this returns me no token but the message that username or password is incorrect

Comment: it works with username "test" & pwd "test", however!! Thank you very much!